# Storage type mismatch

Tags: unbricking, flashtool

I've got tablet Asus MeMo Pad 7 (ME173X). I don't know what happened with him (is it broken physically or by software). Tablet don't respond on buttons, or charger. I connected it to computer dmesg shows (device also disconnect after one second and connect again):

```
usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=0003
usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
cdc_acm 2-1.3:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Sometimes but very rarely dmesg shows also (including above):

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
usbcore: registered new interface driver option
usbserial: USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
```

I found stoc firmware, to flash preloader but every time I got error

```
Storage type mismatch!
scatter storage type is hw_storage_emmc
target storage type is hw_storage_none
```

I was looking some more info. I read some info about meta mode. I tried connect device holding vol up or vol down (both) but device is always recognize as above and flashing also return the same error.

Is there any chance to unbrick this tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try hacking the kernel Readfile and WriteFile using a debugger and inject your data while flashtool is communicating with the device. What you should do is modify the devices output data to match the required output data from a similar device, therefore flashtool will think all is Ok.
It could work.
Or try emmc unbrick .